# Use gst-launch in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, gstreamer

I have configured gstreamer in eclipse(juno). I need to develop a media player accepting mpeg-ts over udp. So, I need to use the udpsrc plugin for the same. For that, I need to use the tool gst-launch, but I have no idea how. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **gst_parse_launch()**.
gst-launch is built around a function called gst_parse_launch().

This function takes a textual representation of a pipeline and turns it into an actual pipeline, which is very handy. You can find it's documentation here: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gstreamer-0.10/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-launch

Also, gst-launch is a tool to be specified on the command line (open a command prompt). Make sure you have set your **path** variable to the bin folder of where you extracted the SDK.

Comment: Hey, thanks. And do you know where to specify this command in eclipse?

Comment: If you're using eclipse, doesn't that mean you're manually coding your gstreamer pipelines? you need to code a C program which provides the functionality you need. check out this tutorial if you need more info: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+2%3A+GStreamer+concepts